# Given a query containing two integers as nodes, find all the children of those two nodes in tree?

Tags: algorithm, tree, tree-traversal

This is my interview question which has the following problem statement

> You are given M queries (1 <= M <= 100000) where every query has 2 integers which behave as nodes of some tree. How will you give all the children(subtree) for these 2 nodes respectively.

Well my approach was naive. I used DFS from both the integers(nodes) for every query but interviewer needed some optimized approach.

More simply, we have to print sub-tree of nodes given in the queries there could be many queries, so we can't run DFS on every node in the query.

Any hints how can I optimize this ?

Comment: What algorithm specifically did you design for it? Can you put some code or pseudo-code?

Comment: find or count? Also, what is the children for the 2 nodes? The intersection of both sets?

Comment: @K.Dackow I just used simple DFS for every query which has 2 integers or nodes and ran DFS for each of them, collecting its subtree.

Comment: @juvian, its simply subtree for both the nodes.

Comment: So its the same as 2 * M queries of a single node? I don´t see why 2 are given. If you need to give the entire subtree as answer for each query, dfs is optimal

Comment: @juvian More simply, we have to print sub-tree of nodes given in the queries there could be many queries, so we can't run DFS on every node in the query.

Comment: @Charles the complexity of DFS on a tree is the same as printing the subtree

Comment: `2 integers which behave as nodes of some tree` , each tree node is identified uniquely by an integer? That means key of the each node is an unique integer. Do one single DFS and store the children of each node in a map and use that map to return answers to future queries.

Answer (score 0):

You could optimize an algorithm that performs DFS on both nodes if one of the nodes is a child of the other.

Suppose Node 2 is a child of Node 1. In this case, calculating the DFS on Node 1 gets all of the children of Node 2, so running DFS again on 2 is inefficient. You could accomplish this by storing intermediate values to avoid recalculation (see [dynamic programming](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming), specifically the example for Fibonacci, about how you can not recalculate values for recursive calls)

Answer (score 0):

For a single query, DFS should be the optimal way. For a larger number of queries here are a few things in my mind that you could do:

1. Cache your results. When a number shows up frequently (say 100 times), save that printed subtree to memory and just return the result when the same number appears again.
2. When caching, also mark all the nodes contained in the cached subtree on your original tree. When a query contains such a node, refer to the cached subtree instead of the original tree since you have done DFS on these nodes as well.
3. As noted by @K. Dackow if a query contains A and B and B is a child of A, you can straight out use the DFS results for B when traversing the tree for A. If permitted you can even look into multiple queries (say 10) and see if there are any nodes that belong to the current subtree you're traversing. You can set up a queue for queries and when doing one DFS traversal, look into the top items in you queue to see if you have met any of the nodes.

Hope this helps!